# Makefile $(info and $(error

Tags: makefile, gnu

I'm using $(info to write something on the output and then I'm checking if there is a nerror or not and then I'm using $(error. What I can see on the output is that in case a multiple $(info functions the $(error output is not always at the end. Sometimes even in the middle. Depend how faster the make process is. It is possible to 'wait' until all $(info will be processed?

```
Exmaple:
$(info a)
$(info a)
$(info a)
$(info a)
$(error ERROR)

Output 1:
a
a
a
a
ERROR

Output 2:
a
a
ERROR
a
a
```

Answer (score 2):

`info` output goes to stdout, and `error` output goes to stderr.  By default stdout is buffered and stderr is unbuffered; that's why they show up differently.  You don't say what version of GNU make you're using, but if you upgrade to a newer version then I believe it will flush both stdout and stderr after every write so you should no longer see this issue (starting with GNU make 4.0 I believe).

Alternatively you could use a tool like [stdbuf](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html), which probably is already installed on your system if it's a GNU/Linux system, to run GNU make.